# How do I tell the netbeans gradle plugin to add generated source files to Source Packages?

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle

I would like to use gradle to automatically generate antlr4 source files from their grammars. This [gradle template](https://github.com/ae6rt/gradle-antlr4-template) does most of the work. What is missing is adding the generated source folder to netbeans so it doesn't class not found errors in the editor. The template has plugin for IDEA IntelliJ, so I tried to see if something similar was possible with netbeans, but haven't been able to find anything. I looked at the [netbeans gradle plugin](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project), but couldn't see away to do it.

Does anyone know how to modify what Netbeans' gradle plugin reads as source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and it's odd. If you use the template with the IDEA plugin left in, the generated source code is added to Source Packages in netbeans. There is nothing to configure. It just works. It seems some of the IDEA plugin functionality is generic.